# Cancel xargs loop command without exit loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, zsh, xargs

i have two example of function in my bash script and BTW i do work most of time on zsh in case that would make a deference in my issue.

first
i declare the following function in the first of script

```
cancel() {
        echo -e "\nCancelling command."
}
```

then i execute functions as below example.

fun1

```
my_fun_xargs(){
    trap cancel SIGINT
    xargs -n1 -P 5 -I {} sh -c "command {}" < test.txt
}
```

fun2

```
my_fun_for(){
    trap cancel SIGINT
    for url in $(cat test.txt);
        do
        command $url ;
    done
}
```

so this script contains a lot of functions which should run one after another.
so every funcion contains list of command and most of it is loop either using for or xargs to speed the process.
MY ISSUE is sometimes command inside function for some reason hang or i need to escape it for now so i put command `trap cancel SIGINT` to till the shell cancel the command not the loop itself and this is working probably in FOR LOOP.

The Q is why that is not working in xargs and it exit the whole command.

is there any special argument in xargs to accept keyboard interpreter `ctrl c` as cancel the current command in loop not the while xargs loop command.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how the fact which shell your are using **most of the time** is related to a problem inside a script which you are running as bash. May I suggest that you remove your zsh tag. Also, I don't see how you are running the script, and inside it how you run the functions. I suggest that you place as first command in the functions a `echo version=$BASH_VERSION` and tell us what you get as output.

Comment: You are specifying that, upon receiving a SIGINT, the program named `cancel` is going to be executed. How did you verify that `cancel` has not been run?

Comment: what i forget to mention command `cancel` it just a function with command echo to print that i'm cancelling the command right now.

Comment: one more thing i did tag zsh in case there is a different behavior related to trap i need to know or something related to escaping xargs without braking the loop and i don't see any problem with that !

Comment: Is `command` the literal keyword `command`, or are you using that to indicate a generic command?

Comment: @WilliamPursell no it just generic command

Comment: The trap command is performed by the process in which you write it. It does not matter, whether the parent process is written in zsh or Fortran or Python or anything else. So it means that you don't see the effect of the `echo` in the canceling command? Maybe you can post a complete, simple example script which everyone can repeat and reproduces the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of detail missing from the question, so I'm speculating.

When you write:

```
my_fun_xargs(){
    trap cancel SIGINT
    xargs -n1 -P 5 -I {} sh -c "command {}" < test.txt
}
```

any SIGINTs that are received will not be acted on by the shell until after `xargs` terminates.  If the commands running by `xargs` do not terminate gracefully (or quickly), that may take some time.  You might be able to mitigate the issue with `xargs ... & wait`, which will cause the shell to react more quickly to the SIGINT.  But this won't address the underlying issue, which seems to be that the processes invoked by xargs are not terminating quickly in response to the signal.

Comment: Is this due to the `-P` option, or a general behaviour of xargs? I had expected that bash would forward the SIGINT to all child processes, and therefor `xargs` should receive it. I found in the xargs man page only a specific treatment (_xargs never terminates its commands_) in the case of `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` signals, and only if `-P` is used. There is no mentioning of other signals.